# which versions of chrome/opera/firefox support IndexedDb?

Tags: html, google-chrome, opera, web-sql, indexeddb

As I see in comments of [this page](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/#toc-final) , I could not understand that if **chrome** supports **IndexedDB** really.

I'm going to write an userscript for chrome/opera/firefox, and decided to not use **localstorage**, I just wanna try IndexedDB instead of localstorage, but before start to write script, I have to know that

**Which versions of chrome/opera/firefox support IndexedDb?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can I Use has [the best summary available](http://caniuse.com/indexeddb).

> Which versions of chrome/opera/firefox support IndexedDb?

Summary of browsers with **full support**.

**Chrome**: Version 11 onward

**Opera**: Version 15 onward

**Firefox**: Version 4 onward

For good measure, **IE**: Version 10 onward

Answer (score 1):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB, the asynchronous API is supported on Chrome version 12 and Firefox 4.0.

Answer (score 1):

http://caniuse.com/#search=indexeddb

Also useful for all the other HTML5 features